# Asp.Net Core / Entity Framework Core - System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[MyClass,System.String]

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to return a json array of my 3rd level depth related data, the issue here is that I get the result with the right property name but with a non clear value content, I failed to find a similar case to solve it. From the returned value message it looks like I am returning a queryable instead of the final result and I need to iterate over it, I've tried several ways to achive that but failed to find the right one.

The json result:

```
[
{
"registeredYear": "System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[MyPath.Groups.GroupYear,System.String]"
}
]
```

The api endpoint

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserGroup>>> GetUserGroupYears(string email, string groupName)
    {
        var groupYears = await _repo.GetUserGroupYears(email, groupName);
        var mappedEntities = _mapper.Map<GroupYearsListDto[]>(groupYears);
        return Ok(mappedEntities);
    }
```

The Repository method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserGroup>> GetUserGroupYears(string email, string groupName)
{
    var userGroupYears = _context.UserGroups
                          .Include(uo => uo.Group.GroupYears)
                            .ThenInclude( oy => oy.Year)
                          .Where(uo => uo.Group.Name == groupName && uo.Email == email );
            return await userGoupYears.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

The used classes:

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupYear> GroupYears { get; }
}

public class GroupYear    {
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    public string YearId { get; set; }
    public virtual Year Year { get; set; }
    public string RegisteredYear { get; set; }
}
```

The data transfer object and the mapping:

```
public class GroupYearsListDto
{
    public string RegisteredYear { get; set; }
}
public CoreMappingProfiles()
{
    CreateMap<UserGroup, GroupYearsListDto>()
      .ForMember(
          dest => dest.RegisteredYear,
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Group.GroupYears.Select(x => x.RegisteredYear))
          );                  
}
```

**Update**: Attaching a debugger shows that the repository method is returning an IQueryable including the correct values and the controller method makes something wrong when mapping. So I think the following line is responsible of that wrong result:

```
var mappedEntities = _mapper.Map<GroupYearsListDto[]>(GroupYears);
```

Comment: First of all, `Select(x => x.RegisteredYear)` is giving an `IEnumerable<string>` that you're mapping to a `string` - that won't work. Second, try `Task<UserGroup[]> GetUserGroupYears` - no need to return an `IEnumerable` there.

Comment: Ok, but OkObjectResult cannot be converted to Task<UserGroup[]>

Comment: You controller can simply be `public ActionResult<UserGroup[]> GetUserGroupYears`. It doesn't make sense to return a `Task` there.

Comment: In the same controller I have another method that works just fine like so: public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserGroup>>> GetUserGroups I can remove IEnumerable but not Task, if I remove Task first that will need to make the method synchronous then it will run into a mapping issue.

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this JSON result:

```
[
  {
    "registeredYear": "System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[MyPath.Groups.GroupYear,System.String]"
  }
]
```

Because you are mapping an `IEnumerable<string>` to a `string`, as I mentioned in my comment. So essentially you are getting the same as:

```cs
CreateMap<UserGroup, GroupYearsListDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.RegisteredYear,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        {
            IEnumerable<string> registeredYears = src.Group.GroupYears.Select(x => x.RegisteredYear);
            return registeredYears.ToString();
        })
    );
```

And `registeredYears.ToString()` is `` "System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[MyPath.Groups.GroupYear,System.String]" ``.

I imagine you will either:

1. Only have one - so do something like: `src.Group.GroupYears.Select(x => x.RegisteredYear).Single()`
2. Have multiples - so do something like: `string.Join(", ", src.Group.GroupYears.Select(x => x.RegisteredYear))`

You have many options, but you need to actually return a `string` to that property or else you will just get the `ToString()` version of `IEnumerable<string>`.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments below, you can try this:

*Repository:*

```cs
public IQueryable<GroupYear> GetGroupYears(string email, string groupName)
{
    return _context
        .UserGroups
        .Where(x => x.Group.Name == groupName && x.Email == email)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Group.GroupYears);
}
```

*Controller:*

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<GroupYearsListDto[]>> GetGroupYears(string email, string groupName)
{
    var groupYears = _repo.GetGroupYears(email, groupName);
    var projection = _mapper.ProjectTo<GroupYearsListDto>(groupYears)
    var mappedEntities = await projection.ToArrayAsync();
    return Ok(mappedEntities);
}
```

*Profile:*

```cs
CreateMap<GroupYears, GroupYearsListDto>();
```

Comment: I have multiples, so tried the 2nd option and it worked, could you please clarify a bit more what this string.Join() did here ?.

Comment: AutoMapper is trying to map from the source (`src`) to the destination (`dest`), which is a `string`. If you provide a source that is not a `string`, AutoMapper will attempt to coerce it by calling `ToString()` on it - that is what was happening to you. So by materializing the `IQueryable` into multiple `string`s and then joining them together, you are properly providing the single `string` source that AutoMapper can successfully map to the `string` destination.

Comment: string.Join(", ", sourceValue) is not the correct function for this case, since it shows the values in a unique string separated with a coma, like so: [{ "registeredYear": "2018, 2019, 2020" }] while they should be an array like so: [{ "registeredYear": "2018", },{ "registeredYear": "2019" }, … ] for an optimal json result. please check this: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This is a good workaround since it is hard to find a way to map deeper collections properties using  automapper, I've tried your solution, it is clean and concise, and it worked fine, so I'll accept it as an answer, Thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW: The two methods (from repo and from controller) can be merged into one method in the controller.